# Always-on-top header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a always-on-top header like the new twitter does.
Explanation: When the user scrolls down the page, I want the header to stay on top of the window.

Somebody know a script that does that? Or can target me how can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use position: fixed; on the header.

```
<div id="header">
content goes here.
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#header { position: fixed; z-index: 9999; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your header a position of `fixed` to make it visible throughout the page. And set the `top` value appropriately along with `width`.

**Example:**

```
#header{
  position:'fixed';
  top:0;
  width:800px;
}
```

Comment: One thing to note is that this behaviour does not work well on Safari for iPhone.

Comment: @Jasper De Bruijn: I knew about IE6 and wonder if there is a workaround for it when using position fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure about IE6, since we no longer support that for our projects. for iPhone solutions, check out http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` on the header in its CSS.

Also, dont forget to set the `left` and `top` attributes to where you want it to go :)